# page does not load if using redirect on angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have a site that runs on angular (link listed below)

If we go to it directly everything works ok. 
If we redirect to the page from another  page, the page doesn't load.

Two examples:

http://www.maaboret.com/

redirect from static page:

http://maaboret.com/not-found

press the HTML5 logo to go back home to see the bug

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me, it is working fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. When I go to not-found and click the HTML5 logo it's working fine